# Snakemake: Only input files can be specified as functions

Tags: snakemake

Snakemake complains that "Only input files can be specified as functions" in the shell line.

```
def get_filename(wildcards):
    sampleid = wildcards.sample.split['-'][1]
    GeneFuse_vcf= f"{sampleid}.fusion.vcf"
    return GeneFuse_vcf

rule GeneFuse:
    input:
        bam_path = f"{outputdir}/"+"{sample}/13_genefusion"
    params:
        svabaflow = config["svabaflow"],
    output:
        GeneFuse_vcf = get_filename
    shell:
        "{params.svabaflow} {input} {wildcards.sample}"
```

In the rule GenefUSE, my {sample} format is ctn-305A26000547

and i want to tell snakemake that my outputfile(GeneFuse_vcf) is named 305A26000547.fusion.vcf
Ofcourse,if the {sample} is ctn-367A23594285,the filename should be "367A23594285.fusion.vcf"

Any suggestion to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Snakemake uses the output filenames to determine wildcard values and input filenames. It doesn't work the other way around. In your example you ask snakemake to determine the output filename from the wildcards, but snakemake derives the wildcards from the output filename - that can't work. Do you know how your output files will be called or will you have a list of samples which you can provide to snakemake? That's a common approach.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
i have a list of samples and i try to provide it to snakemake like this:
SAMPLES = ["ct1-305A26000547","ct5-367A23594285","ct9-302A67458112"]
SAMPLEID = list(map(lambda x: x.split('-')[1],SAMPLES))

But how can i write the "rule all" and "rule GeneFuse".

Comment: That's important and good information! If you already have the list of IDs, then it should be easy. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you already have the list of `SAMPLEIDS` as you state in the comment, you can construct an `rule all` which calls `rule GeneFuse` like this:

```py
rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}.fusion.vcf", sampleid=SAMPLEIDS),
    default_target: True


rule GeneFuse:
    input:
        bam_path=f"{outputdir}/" + "{sample}/13_genefusion",
    params:
        svabaflow=config["svabaflow"],
    output:
        GeneFuse_vcf="{sample}.fusion.vcf",
    shell:
        "{params.svabaflow} {input} {wildcards.sample}"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
rule all:
    input:
        expand("{sample}.fusion.vcf", sampleid=SAMPLEIDS),
    default_target: True

dictionary = {"305A26000547": "ct1-305A26000547",
              "367A23594285": "ct5-367A23594285",
              "02A67458112": "ct9-302A67458112"}

def get_path(wildcards):
    ss = dictionary[wildcards.sample]
    bam_path= f"{outputdir}/{ss}/13_genefusion"
    return bam_path

rule GeneFuse:
    input:
        get_path,
    params:
        svabaflow=config["svabaflow"],
    output:
        GeneFuse_vcf="{sample}.fusion.vcf",
    shell:
        "{params.svabaflow} {input} {wildcards.sample}"
```